# why the loops is not working? why in the local variable "y" is always int and s counter = 1 = int

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

as a mandatory assignment at my university the asked us to use c# I'm trying to build a compiler of 3 phases and this is the first time in my life to write in c# and first time to work in a large project like this
1)parser
2)error checker
3)memory
why the loops  is not working? why in the local variable "y" is always int and s counter = 1 = "identifier"

```
        foreach (string word in words)
            {
                string y = "";
                string z = "";
                string m = "";
                string er = "";
                string numb = "";
                string vari = "";
               List<string> s = new List<string>();


                if (word == "/")
                {
                    y += word;
                    y += "= operand\n";
                    s.Add(word);

                }
                else if (word == "+")
                {
                    y += word;
                    y += "= operand\n";
                    s.Add(word);

                }
                else if (word == "*")
                {
                    y += word;
                    y += "= operand\n";
                    s.Add(word);
```

Comment: Could you please post a shorter code sample with the exact issue?

Comment: firstly, your code is not **functioning at all** (a lot of syntax errors) and it's not **well-formated**. I suggest you to fix all the syntax errors and format it first.

Comment: You are trying to build something more like interpreter, but not a compiler. Anyway, that's exactly not how you can build anything which is parsing programming language syntax.

Comment: More full-stops please

Comment: @Ouarzy will help you with the problem you described, though your error checking is rather gnarly. You write all these lines just for one possible instance of the user writing it's input, you'll end up having this huuuge pile of ifs in the end... if one of em is wrong, you'll never find which one!

Comment: I've removed parts of your code that had obviously have nothing to do with your code (empty methods etc). you should try to only include the code that is relevant to your issue. I'm sure there is more but I daren't touch that foreach loop, it scares me

Answer (score 0):

What about replace your foreach loop by a for?
http://www.david-amador.com/2009/12/csharp-foreach-vs-for-loop/

Your loop will look like:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < words.Count; index++)
    {
        var word = words[index];
        //doStuff
    }
```